# Jquery Sortable touch funcitonality ie 11 windows 8.1

Tags: jquery-ui, touch, internet-explorer-11, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I'm having a lot of trouble getting the JQuery Sortable functionality working on my Windows 8.1 device which is running ie11.

I had this working on an iPad through the TouchPunch library, but I've had no luck with the new Dell Tablet I'm working with.

I've ran the webapp through Chrome on the tablet, and the sortable functionality works very smoothly.  Does anyone have any ideas how I can get it up and running on Internet Explorer 11?

I have tried pulling down various versions of [Touch Punch](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) on GitHub, some which attempt to deal with ie10, but I've found nothing that really works with ie11, so I would be glad for some pointers.  If I run the [Jquery Sortable Demo][2] on the device, I am able to drag just about by holding to the left of the table row and pulling down at the right point, but this is in no way usable.

Ideally, jQuery mobile would include the sortable functions, but it does not.

***Just to be clear, if I go to the sortable example below on my tablet:

[Jquery Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

then I can't really get the sort funcitonality to work.

To the above source code, I have added touchpunch library, and also added

```
-ms-touch-action: none;
```

to my #sortable class.

According to some online, this should fix the issue on ie10 and ie11, but I'm not seeing it make the remotest bit of difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, were you able to get it working on IE11 windows 8 tablet? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: After posting the comment, I found the solution. -ms-touch-action: none; worked for me. Thanks. More info - http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2012/10/24/jquery-ui-and-windows-8-and-internet-explorer-10-touch-screens.aspx

Comment: Hi, is it Sortable you were having trouble with, or draggable?  I am able to get draggable working, but not sortable.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the black box that appears on a "hold" right click event.  If part of the box's edge goes over the edge of the browser window, then I can move the records fine, which is why I can move things by holding down at the rows' far lefts.  Disabling right click does not disable the box.

Comment: Sorry I did not have sorting req. Only draggable which is now working with your suggested solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there was a simple answer to this in the end, although it took me a long time to find it.  I started by trying to intercept touch events and failing, which eventually led me to realise that I had added the site to Compatibility View (Settings -> Compatibility View Settings), where I also had checked "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" and "Use Microsoft Compatibility lists").

I think this reverts to the site displaying in ie7 mode.  Due to this, I think there are issues with the MS-touch commands being recognised, and so -ms-touch-action: none was having no effect.

To be clear, then, referencing touchpunch, whilst also using -ms-touch-action: none, should get the jQuery sortable functionality working in ie11 - just be sure to check your compatibility settings!